# Statistically Approximating Clicks From Limited Data

Tags: time-series, data-mining, approximation

Assume a business started in January 2014.

I have the following daily data (from June 2014 to December 2014):
1. Number of people who joined the website; 
2. Number of people who left the website; 
3. Number of clicks in total the website obtained from people (i.e. theres no way of obtaining clicks other than through people who joined the website at anytime).
Assume I cannot obtain January - May 2014 data.

Problem:
The number of clicks in total the website obtained may be clicks from people who joined the website before June.

What I want to approximate:
How many clicks were made by the number of people who joined the website strictly between June - December 2014 so that I can make a better approximation of the total clicks/person.

I think a statistical time series method to provide some sort of trend needs to be used but I'm not sure what method to research to solve the above problem. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

What you effectively have are two time-series: Number of clicks per day and Change of users per day (with the total user count being unknown) and you want to estimate the impact of changing the number of users on the number of clicks.

The problem is hard because:

**a.** you have observational so you can never be really certain about
   the causality between changing the user count and the clicks

**b.** presumably there are many reasons causing changes in the number of clicks which means that a model based on a change of users will be very weak in its explanatory power

**c.** time-series models usually involve past values of a single variable, while what you technically want is a time-series model with exogenous variables (change in the number of users) which are a both more complex to estimate and interpret.
If you want to go down this road see: A [regression with ARMA errors](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-timeseries-regression.pdf), which would be my weapon of choice, other options include an ARMAX model or a dynamic linear model (see [here](http://helios.fmi.fi/~lainema/dlm/dlmtut.html) for nice tutorial).

If you want to keep it dirty (and simple) my first instinct would be to look at the relationship between the absolute change in daily clicks

$Y_t = \text{#Website clicks day t} - \text{#Website clicks day t - 1}$

and the daily absolute change in users

$X_t = \text{#Users that joined on day t} - \text{#Users that left on day t}$

You could start with a simple [linear model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and take it from there:

$Y_t = b_1X_t + \epsilon$
where $\epsilon$ follows a Guassian distribution.

Alternatively, you could also try:
$Y_t = b_1X_{\text{joined},t} + b_2X_{\text{left},t} + \epsilon$ in order to model that the leavers and joiners have a different click rate.

The number of clicks purely by new users over the period June-December would then be: $b_1 (\text{#Users joined})$ in the period June to December.

Also keep in mind the many simplifying assumptions you will be making along the way, such as: clicking behavior doesn't change over time, etc.

**Alternative approach:**
You could also try to explicitly model the total number of users $Y_t$. You know the number of users that joined $X_{\text{joined},t}$ and left $X_{\text{left},t}$ daily over a period of 6 months. 
You can model $Y_t$ as a Poisson process, or even simpler $X_{\text{joined},t} \sim Pois(\lambda_1)$ and $X_{\text{left},t} \sim Pois(\lambda_2)$ respectively. But the major issue is that this would assume that the rates at which you acquire and loose users is constant which usually doesn't apply for website visits! If you believe the rates $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ of users joining and leaving are constant, great!

The maximum likelihood estimate for the rate of users joining each day is just the average of users joined per day. Multiply that with the number of days in total since existence of the website and you have your total user count.

Unfortunately, if you realize the rate is not constant $\lambda_1$ becomes $\lambda_{1}(t)$ and you would have to [estimate an inhomogeneous Poisson process](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/icrsa03.pdf). The trouble with that is that since you are missing the preceding part of the data, it would be probably very tricky to "just extrapolate" the rate backwards, so I don't think that approach is a clear win.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with the linear model is suppose I calculate change in website clicks daily for 6 months, net people (which is users joined - left) and regress it, those 'clicks' still include clicks from users who joined before time t. This is the main challenge I'm finding. I think I need to subtract some sort of time series from the other just unsure how/what. If I knew the # joined/leaving per day and the # clicks those people only contributed per day I could just find a simple average (which is sufficient for an approximation).

Comment: Regarding "those 'clicks' still include clicks from users who joined before time t" - the coefficients of the regression model as proposed above would tell you, what is the average impact on the number of clicks if you add one additional user. Sure the number of clicks depends also on the total count of users, but it also depends on many other factors which you are not taking into account. The bottomline is that you are not trying to find a great model predicting the number of clicks but rather to correctly estimate the effect of new users on clicks. Tell me if I'm missing something.

Comment: This helped a lot - thanks! To clarify: say Y = 10X + 50, one additional follower will contribute to 60 clicks? Or should I do say, there are 50 new followers gained in a 3 month period, so total clicks in 3 months = (10x50)+50 = 550 clicks, so 11 clicks on average (550/50) per (net) user ie. 4*11 = 44 clicks per user per year on average? Or impose a 0 intercept constraint and take the gradient only?

Comment: I would fit a model without intercept. It just seems more natural since with 0 users you should have exactly 0 clicks. I will modify the answer to point it out.

Comment: @DinoAbraham: If you need a distance-like measure for time series comparison, it might make sense to take a look at [dynamic time warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).

Comment: means-to-meaning I tried this on multiple data but there isn't always a linear relation unfortunately (e.g. gradient shows up to be 0.000001 for some data and 50 for others). What do you recommend in this case?

Comment: Did the models you fitted on your subsamples all show the gradient to be statistically significant? I would presume that with only 365/2 datapoints, you are risking to have too little data to test the statistical significance of the gradient, even if you use all of them. can you post a scatterplot of the daily change in users and change in clicks?

Comment: woops looks like i exchanged Y_t and X_t - attempting properly now - sorry! :)

Comment: tried it - works well for high clicks/users but not as well for companies with not as many clicks per user (in some cases it shows 0.1 clicks per user which is a little hard to digest given the company). wondering about a way around this? shall i upload some sample data?

Comment: There are many reasons why the regression might fail, my first suspicion would be outliers that mess up the fit.

Comment: means-to-meaning had a chance to try the 2 methods above but we still have an issue I think. Suppose Jun - Dec 2014 there are 1000 clicks and 500 new (net) followers joined. We are basically trying to estimate a correction factor as from those 1000, maybe only 700 clicks are from the 500 (net) followers who joined. The issues with the method above is (i) if someone unfollows they cannot 'click' (ii) the Poisson method is good except we won't always know when the website started (I know above we do) (iii) clicks is dependent also on spend data (I have a daily time series of this).

Comment: @means-to-meaning - bump ;)

Comment: "if someone unfollows they cannot 'click'" I don't see why this matters. The model equation is only mentioning the number of users that leave, not their clicks. iii. If you have data for each new user, why didn't you just use the amount of data as proxy for clicks - that's the straightforward thing to do, though it changes your question completely.

Comment: @means-to-meaning - the issue is say you have 1000 clicks in Jan 15 and you know 100 users joined (pretend 0 left). We cannot say click/per user is 1000/100 = 10 as from those 1000 some clicks may be from users outside those 100 ie. users who joined in Dec 14 or Nov 14 or sometime else. I need to assign clicks/user 'just' for the month and i'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: You are merely re-iterating the same exact question you have posted using an example. See my answer above! These comments are mostly used for clarifications. I believe there is a chat forum for interactive discussions.

Comment: means-to-meaning: ive been through this thread again and again but still don't seem to be getting how i can determine the number of clicks a new user produces with the data i have. the models above cannot really be used because there will be fluctuations in people joining/leaving (because of various factors e.g. spend on marketing) and clicks ofc will vary as a result too. also i doubt its linear - eventually 'x' # of people can only produce so many clicks. what do you recommend please? (not sure how to move this to chat).